# Jira Cloud link alias not working from REST API

Tags: api, jira

When setting the Description of an issue using the REST API, the link alias format is as described Link Text and appears exactly in this format, however it is not converted to an alias. If I remove the ending close parenthesis and then re-type the parenthesis, it will convert to an alias. If I create a new link alias through the interface it works, but through the API.